# pyspark withcolumn expression only if column exists

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
%python

def has_column(df, col):
    try:
        df[col]
        return True
    except AnalysisException:
        return False
      
df = spark.createDataFrame([ \
    ("C","I"), \
    ("I","I"), \
    ("C","B"), \
], ["B2B","E1J"])

df.show()
    
+---+---+
|B2B|E1J|
+---+---+
|  C|  I|
|  I|  I|
|  C|  B|
+---+---+
```

Now this is what i want to do : Check if a column exists and only if it exists, then check its value and based on that assign a value to the flag column.This works fine as long as the check is done on a valid column, as below

```
df.withColumn("flag",when( ((lit(has_column(df, "B2B"))) & (col("B2B")=="C") ) , 1).otherwise(0)).show()


+---+---+----+
|B2B|E1J|flag|
+---+---+----+
|  C|  I|   1|
|  I|  I|   0|
|  C|  B|   1|
+---+---+----+
```

The problem that i have is that these check conditions are not static but instead, they are read from an external file and generated on the fly and it may have columns that the actual dataframe does not have and causes error's as below.

Any ideas to fix this ?

For e.g:

```
df.withColumn("flag", \
              when( \
                  (lit(has_column(df, "GBC"))) & (col("GBC")=="C") |   \
                  (lit(has_column(df, "B2B"))) & (col("B2B")=="C")     \
                , 1))   \
              .otherwise(0).show()


org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve &#39;`GBC`&#39; given input columns: [B2B, E1J];;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `col('GBC')`. You can use following code to do prediction on a column may not exist.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def for_exist_column(df, col, pre):
    if col in df.columns:
        return pre(df[col])
    else:
        return F.lit(False)


df = spark.createDataFrame([ \
    ("C","I"), \
    ("I","I"), \
    ("C","B"), \
], ["B2B","E1J"])

df.show()

df.withColumn("flag",F.when(for_exist_column(df, 'B2B', lambda c: c=='C'), 1).otherwise(0)).show()

df.withColumn("flag", F.when(for_exist_column(df, 'GBC', lambda c: c=='C') | for_exist_column(df, 'B2B', lambda c: c=='C'), 1).otherwise(0)).show()
```